# How to access my home server (XAMPP Apache Tomcat) from anywhere?

Tags: networking, router, internet, apache-http-server, modem

I'm running XAMPP in my windows 7 system. I have a broadband Internet connection powered by Binatone wireless ADSL2+ Modem Router, its a Dynamic IP connection, i configured NO-IP in my system and i have my own domain name www.xyz.myftp.org but i can't able to access the my tomcat server. It is redirecting to my IP and i can able to view my Modem page, but my server is not accessable. I also configure my server virutal host file **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mymail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/home-PC/Music/"
    ServerName xyz.myftp.org
    ServerAlias xyz.myftp.org
    ErrorLog "logs/xyz.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/xyz.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you configured your router to forward the ports? Did you set up no-ip with your router's public or internal IP address?

Comment: My no-ip is configure with my public ip address only and i also have the DUC(Dynamic Update Client) installed, i have to check my router for ports forwarding.

Comment: Also, I would be careful blatantly exposing something like your `Music/` folder. If you use iTunes for instance, that means anyone can download your music or access your backup files. They can also grab your library and the IDs/keys used for interacting with iPhones/iPads.

Answer (score 0):

**Start here with the port:**

If port 80 is being used by another service or server Your Server will not start. Before starting your server make sure you do not have another service running on Port 80. The following check works on XP home and XP Pro:

```
Start a command prompt start > run > type in cmd
At the command prompt type netstat -ano | find "LISTENING" | find ":80"
```

This produces a list of what ports are being occupied. Any IP followed by :80 means port 80 is being used. You now have the following options:

```
Disable (kill process) the offending items
```

The path to folder for your server must not contain spaces. Do not use "C:\Program Files", for example (which has other problems as well, such as restricted permissions and system restore inconsistencies). We recommend installing to the drive root, such as "C:\" or "D:\" for simplicity, but other locations, such as "C:\test1\appserver" work just as well.

Note: The space character restriction is generic and applies to other WAMP stacks as well. Many applications that will be hosted on the server do not tolerate spaces in paths. The system restore issue applies mainly to individual component installs.

If the current installation is on a faulty path, the situation can easily be resolved by just moving the your server directory to a proper location. You do not have to delete the directory and reinstall. For example, just rename "D:\bad path\Your Server" to "D:\good_loc\Your Server".

In addition the controller provides a menu option to edit or view the Your Server PAC file. Creating an Apache Vhost add an entry to this file. Entries in the PAC file resolve domain names to local host allowing testing without the need for a DNS entry or writing an entry in the Windows hosts file.

**Installing your Website or Test pages**

Server root folder:

B) Web pages are served from folder Your Server\www , which is commonly referred to as the server root folder.

Simply copy your Website into this root folder.

The root folder www already contains a very simple web-site consisting of a single page named index.php including its associated folders css and images. Its purpose is to provide a test page, allowing you to
confirm that the server is functioning properly.

US Folder structure

Before installing your Website, you can delete the index.php file and folders css and images.

Don't delete the .htaccess and favicon.ico files. They have the following purposes:

- .htaccess - This file is part of the server security and should not be deleted.
- favicon.ico - This is a small image file displayed in a browser next to a Web page name.

You can replace this with your own file, but use the name favicon.ico so browsers will display it properly.

Note: Having a favicon image is not a requirement, but modern browsers attempt to load this image by default. If your server does not contain one, an error is logged in Apache's log file.

**General notes**

Note 1: Unix installations use a root folder named htdocs. When using an application installation guide that refers to htdocs, use folder www instead.

Note 2: The file structure is not static. For example, running Vhost creates the new folder Your Server\vhosts containing Vhost root folders.

The default server name is localhost. Use this to access pages as follows:

Index Pages

To access index pages (such as index.htm, index.html, index.php) type the following into your browser.

http://localhost/

Specific pages

Display a specific page by appending its name to the server name. For example, if your test page is named test.php, then type the following into your browser:

http://localhost/test.php

Note: The Apache server automatically searches for index pages and displays the first one it finds. If it cannot find an index page, a directory listing is displayed instead.

Change Access

Server configuration uses an .htaccess file located in root folder Your Server\www. It is pre-configured to allow local access only. Four lines (Apache directives) control who can access to the server. These lines are edited as follows:

Local Access

H) Click radio button Local Access

Alternatively edit file Your Server\www.htaccess and uncomment (remove #) four lines as shown:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
```

Local and Intranet Access

I) Click radio button Local and Intranet Access

Alternatively edit file Your Server\www.htaccess and uncomment (remove #) four lines as shown:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 10.0.0.0/8
Allow from ::1
```

Local, Intranet and Internet Access

J) Click radio button Local, Intranet and Internet Access

Alternatively edit file Your Server\www.htaccess and comment (add #) to four lines as shown:

```
#Order Deny,Allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from 127.0.0.1
#Allow from ::1
```